# Do I need to use NVARCHAR rather than VARCHAR to properly store UTF8 characters in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, character-set

I want my Oracle database to properly store ALL possible UTF8 characters. If NLS_CHARSET is set to AL32UTF8 is that all I need to do? Or do I need to also make sure I use NCHAR and NVARCHAR rather than CHAR and VARCHAR to properly store UTf8 characters?

Answer (score 11):

Good question. I'll give a simplified answer.

Oracle supports two character sets simultaneously, by way of different datatypes and parameters. A "normal" database-wide characterset and a "national" characterset.

Now, the "normal" characterset affects the way that `VARCHAR2`, `CHAR` and `CLOB` data is stored. The "national" characterset affects the way that `NVARCHAR2`, `NCHAR` and `NCLOB` data is stored.

These are dictated at database creation time. For example:

```
CREATE DATABASE .... 
CHARACTER SET AL32UTF8
NATIONAL CHARACTER SET AL16UTF16 
..... BLAH;
```

You can see these by checking in your DB. For example:

```
SQL> select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter like '%CHARACTERSET';

PARAMETER                      VALUE
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
NLS_CHARACTERSET               WE8MSWIN1252
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET         AL16UTF16

SQL>
```

`NLS_CHARACTERSET` is for `CHAR`/`VARCHAR2`, `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` is for `NCHAR`/`NVARCHAR2`.

If your normal characterset is UTF%, you're generally safe staying away from the `N%` datatypes unless you have some strange internationalisation requirements. If so, feel free to edit your question!

Comment: I guess Phil is spot on. Just one point. Be careful if you end up using VARCHAR2 (or CHAR) and NVARCHAR2 (or NCHAR). They can cause issues (and I believe Phil knows it... :) )